# Sharing my Google Pay account with my 16-year-old

Tags: children, google-finance, teenager

How can I share my Google Pay account with my 16-year-old so they can use it from their phone?
I already have Google pay set up on my phone.

Thank you! I'd appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Pretty detailed explanation here. Did this not work for you?  https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-contacts#:~:text=Access%20the%20payments%20profile%20Settings,optional)%2C%20and%20email%20address.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: I can't seem to add another user. It does say something about needing a business account to do it. Could you shed some light on this pls?